# WooCommerce Checkout Manager overwrites custom attributes if activated is there a work around for this?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Am trying to make checkout fields read only in my checkout form, and the code below works perfectly if Woo-Commerce Checkout Manager is deactivated, but the plugin is mandatory for the way the site is configured,
Is there a work-around to accomplish this?

Is there a different hook i can use to obtain the same result?
Is there a different plugin which can give me what i want ?

```
add_filter('woocommerce_checkout_fields','customization_readonly_billing_fields');
function customization_readonly_billing_fields($checkout_fields){
    foreach ( $checkout_fields['billing'] as $key => $field ){  
            if( $key == 'billing_country' || $key == 'billing_state' || $key == 'billing_suburb' ){
             $checkout_fields['billing'][$key]['custom_attributes'] = array('disabled'=>'disabled');
            }else{
             $checkout_fields['billing'][$key]['custom_attributes'] = array('readonly'=>'readonly');        
            }
    }
    //var_dump($checkout_fields['billing']);
    return $checkout_fields;
}
```